# how to create a cookie which can store list/Array

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

In my current project I have to show a Popup(Welcome Info) every time he/she login to the site. In the Popup user have a option(Onclick CheckBox) to hide the Popup for 30days.

I'm achieving this by saving a UserUniqueId to cookie(Which should be an array/list) when he/she click checkBox on popup. As Below

```
    var UniqueId = "xxx";
    var uIDCookies = [];

    // looping to get all the values that are stored in cookie 
    $.each($.cookie(), function(i, v) {
        uIDCookies.push(i);
    });

    // if current userUID not found in cookie then showing popup  
    if (($.inArray(UniqueId, uIDCookies)) === -1) {
        //show popup
    } else {
        // hide popup
    }

    // create cookie and set expire time 
    $('.checkBox').on('click', function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var minutes = 3;
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
            $.cookie(UniqueId,  { expires: date, path: '/' });
            //hide popup
    });
```

No matter what I'm looping through all cookie values that are stored on client browser so, I feel that there could be a better way to achieve this. Suggestions Please..!!

Comment: `$.cookie(UniqueId)`?

Comment: There would never be more than one user in the cookie unless two users signed in to the site on the same computer on the same browser.  Is that a scenario you need to handle?  Secondly it's a really bad idea to save user id's in a non encrypted cookie.

Comment: Cookies are stored localy on the user's computer. I don't get why you should have multiple uuid while you only have one user.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the cookie with the UniqueID as the name. Just check if that cookie already exists directly:

```
if (! $.cookie(UniqueId) ) {
        //show popup
    } else {
        // hide popup
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very suspiciously like a very bad design choice, but to answer the question as asked, just serialise the array and convert the string to Base64. Then you can parse it back out again afterwards.

As mentioned in the OP's comments though, there are very few edge cases where this is necessary in the scenario you have mentioned. Also, don't set or get cookies in jQuery. Use your serverside language to gather and set cookie information whereever possible, and send it to the page where needed. Don't use cookies where it would be better to use a data store. You have no control over the cookie information once it has been set, and so they can be a security vector into your application.

Cookies are stored per profile, per browser, per user, per computer, and so aren't always the best way to store this info. Instead, consider adding two columns to your user profile table, `DisplayWelcomeMessage` as a boolean, and `SuppressWelcomeMessageExpiry` as a DateTime. That way, the info is set per user, not per cookie. It allows the application to be more scalable, as it gives the user the option to turn it back on before the expiry runs out.